# Painting Prefinished baseboard

Tags: baseboard

I'm looking at purchasing some [prefinished baseboard](http://www.menards.com/main/home-decor/mouldings/interior-prefinished-mouldings/prefinished-base-moulding/oak/7-16-x-2-3-4-x-14-prefinished-golden-oak-colonial-base/p-1881795-c-7627.htm) to save me some time. My plan is just to paint it white. Am I correct in my thinking that since it is prefinished, I should just be able to paint it and go?

Comment: You mean pre-primed, right?

Comment: No prefinished. See link

Comment: Isn't the point of buying prefinished baseboard that you DON'T have to finish it? If you want to paint it, don't get the prefinished stuff. Get the preprimed stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that's a very good idea. First of all, the wood is already sealed, so the paint isn't going to adhere very well. Second, you're going to waste a lot of money by purchasing nice grainy oak baseboard, since you're paying for the color and grain that are going to be covered up by paint. You can save a dollar per linear foot or more by going with some finger-jointed pine or MDF pre-primed white baseboard that you then finish off with a coat of paint.

Comment: I agree, on top of wasted money, the base will need to be sanded to allow a coat of primer to be applied, and then another sanding before the finish coat is applied.